# .net 6 load config dependent on environment

Tags: .net-core, configuration, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have a .net 6 project, and I have two json files for config, `appsettings.json` & `appsettings.Development.json`.

In my launch settings, I have my `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Development`. In `Program.cs` I have the standard code of:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

I can see that the settings from `appsettings.json` are loaded when `CreateBuilder` is run.

I read from a Microsoft site, that, if you have an environmental appsettings file loaded, by default, it should replace the appsettings.json file. But in my project, this is not the behaviour.

This is meaning, for my connection strings, I am getting those in `appsettings.json`, not `appsettings.Development.json`

I have tried adding the file myself using:

```
var environment = builder.Environment;

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{enironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
});
```

But, this does not override either.

I am presuming that I am missing a setting, or something similar to get it to overwrite the config.

Is anyone able to shed any light on what my mistake is?

Comment: That is a behavior out-of-the-box (support of `appsettings.{enironment.EnvironmentName}.json`) and personally I have never had problems with it. Can you post a full repro somewhere?

Comment: When you have used it, is it as simple as the Environment file replaces the appsettings file, and when you access config, it is simply from the environment? 

I can't post the project, it is a work project, not a personal one, but I will see if I can get another project to behave the same way

Comment: No, there is no replacing happening. Configuration in .NET Core is hierarchical, if value is missing from one provider the framework will try to read it from another in order depended on order of registration (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#default-application-configuration-sources)).

Comment: Sorry, wrong phrasing from me there. I had read that, and, fundamentally, appsettings.json is the last thing it uses, so, in the presence of any of the other files, it should be using them over it. At least my understanding of what should happens seems correct, even if it isn't happening

Comment: By default, `appsettings.{enironment.EnvironmentName}.json` is **merged** with `appsettings.{enironment.EnvironmentName}.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this, but, I have no idea why it caused an issue in the first place.

I am using dapper, and I have an extension method to register it.

When this was not working, I was doing the following:

```
var db = "test";
builder.Services.AddDapperSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(db));
```

I changed it to be:

```
var db = "test";
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(db);

builder.Service.AddDapperSqlServer(connectionString);
```

And it now works. If anyone knows why, I would love to know.